# java can't connect to jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to set up a connection with a MySQL database with Java using JDBC.

But when I try to do this, I get some errors.
I'm sure the problem is not because of a wrong MySQL server setting, because I tried to connect with MySQL Workbench, and this works.

I use this Java code to set up de JDBC connection:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class SQLConnection {

    public static SQLConnection instance = new SQLConnection();
    public static String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/canbusdata";
    public static String USER= "root";
    public static String PSW = "root";

    public SQLConnection()
    {
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        System.out.println("-------- MySQL JDBC Connection ------------\n");

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Where is your MySQL JDBC Driver?");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        System.out.println("MySQL JDBC Driver Registered!");
        Connection connection = null;

        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,USER,PSW);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console: \n");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return connection;
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
-------- MySQL JDBC Connection ------------

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Where is your MySQL JDBC Driver?
MySQL JDBC Driver Registered!
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
Connection Failed! Check output console: 

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at SQLConnection.getConnection(SQLConnection.java:21)
    at Start.ProcessData(Start.java:109)
    at Start.main(Start.java:21)
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/canbusdata
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at SQLConnection.getConnection(SQLConnection.java:31)
    at Start.ProcessData(Start.java:109)
    at Start.main(Start.java:21)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Start.ProcessData(Start.java:110)
    at Start.main(Start.java:21)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Check your classpath. Where are you running this from: IDE or prompt?

Comment: Paste your classpath settings (pom or similar) if you want some advice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java connectivity with MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/java-connectivity-with-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you haven't configured your JDBC driver in your project. Make sure to add it to the classpath before running it (through command line or IDE based).

Answer (score 1):

Download this jar and include in Built path it will work

[mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar](https://code.google.com/p/find-ur-pal/downloads/detail?name=mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar&)

Hope this helps.